# AjaxControlToolKit v16.1.0.0 TabContainer

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, tabcontainer

I upgraded to the latest version of AjaxControlToolKit and now none of my Ajax tab controls work.  Previously they worked fine.

After the upgrade, my tab controls defaulted to invisible.  I can force visibility with style="visibility:visible" in the tabContainer tag.  Then it appears and looks ok, except that clicking on the tab headers does nothing.  I tried setting them all with Enabled="True" with no effect.

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="test1.aspx.vb" Inherits="Myapp.test1" %>
 <%@ Register TagPrefix="ajaxToolKit"  Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"  %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmTest" runat="server">
          <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <br /><br /><br /><br />
        <ajaxToolKit:TabContainer ID="hello" runat="server" OnClientActiveTabChanged="TabChanged()" ActiveTabIndex="0">
            <ajaxToolKit:TabPanel><HeaderTemplate>First Tab</HeaderTemplate>
                <ContentTemplate>Text on first tab.</ContentTemplate>

            </ajaxToolKit:TabPanel>
            <ajaxToolKit:TabPanel><HeaderTemplate>Second tab</HeaderTemplate>
                <ContentTemplate>Can't get this tab to appear.</ContentTemplate>

            </ajaxToolKit:TabPanel>


        </ajaxToolKit:TabContainer>
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to removed OnClientActiveTabChanged and ActiveTabIndex and it worked correctly.  The older version was not so fussy and did not mind me having OnClientActiveTabChanged pointing to a missing function.

It is worth noting that I barked up the wrong tree for a long time because the problem seems to occur with ANYTHING is wrong with either the TabContainer or TabPanel tag.  In my initial test code to try to identify the issue I stripped out everything and got the same problem without either of these two tags.  However it turned out to be a different reason (I omitted runat="server" in the TabPanels).